# Employee available for task between a date range

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I have been working on a employee work management project and I am a little stuck. I have 3 tables:

```
1:  employees

    empid,       empFirst     empLast
    1            jon          smith
    2            mark         road
    3            jane         hall
```

```
2:  holiday

    id        employee id      datestart       dateend
    1         2                2015-08-07      2015-08-12
    2         3                2015-07-4       2015-07-11
    3         2                2015-07-20      2015-07-24
```

```
3: Task Assigned

   id      taskid        assignedTo(userid)        startTask      endTask
   1       1               1                     2015-07-10      2015-07-14
   2       2               2                     2015-07-29      2015-07-29
   3       2               3                     2015-07-18      2015-07-30
   4       3               2                     2015-08-30      2015-09-03
   5       4               2                     2015-09-10      2015-09-03
```

I'm not sure how to go about querying the tables to see who is available for a task in a date range (multiple user assigned to the same task). I have a query which I would here:

so if you take the holiday table out if the equation and just run the query below

```
SELECT employees.empId, employees.empFirst, employees.empLast
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN taskassigned 
ON employees.empId = taskassigned.assignedTo
WHERE taskassigned.assignedTo IS NULL or  
 not (taskassigned.startTask  BETWEEN '2015-07-29 14:30:00' AND '2015-07-29 18:30:00' 
   or taskassigned.endTask  BETWEEN '2015-07-29 14:30:00' AND '2015-07-29 18:30:00')
```

the result I get is:

```
empId  empFirst empLast
1      jon      smith   (he is available)
2      mark     road    
2      mark     road
```

As you can see Mark is not available on this date (in the task table).

I would like the query the holiday table first to see if they are on holiday then the task table to see if they already have a task on the date range then the result to show me how is available for the task.

Comment: Too tired for a complete answer, but, try thinking about it a different way. You're trying to see if the employee is free between `2015-07-29 14:30:00` and `2015-07-29 18:30:00`, so, in your `WHERE` clause, see if  `2015-07-29 14:30:00` is not between `taskassigned.startTask` and `taskassigned.endTask`, and if `2015-07-29 18:30:00` is not between `taskassigned.startTask` and `taskassigned.endTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this at the moment, but try:

```
SELECT employees.empId, employees.empFirst, employees.empLast
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN taskassigned 
ON employees.empId = taskassigned.assignedTo
LEFT JOIN holiday
ON employees.empId = holiday.employeeId
WHERE (
    taskassigned.assignedTo IS NULL
    OR (
        '2015-07-29 14:30:00'  NOT BETWEEN taskassigned.startTask AND taskassigned.endTask
        AND '2015-07-29 18:30:00'  NOT BETWEEN taskassigned.startTask AND taskassigned.endTask
    )
)
AND (
    holiday.employeeId IS NULL
    OR (
        '2015-07-29 14:30:00'  NOT BETWEEN holiday.dateStart AND holiday.dateEnd
        AND '2015-07-29 18:30:00'  NOT BETWEEN holiday.dateStart AND holiday.dateEnd
    )
)
```

This would check to see if the specified start date doesn't fall inbetween the assigned task's start or end date, and if the specified end date doesn't fall inbetween the assigned task's start or end date, and then do the same for holidays.

Comment: Hi Will Thanks for your answer but it still not the right result I was looking for. still get  mark is available this is this because he has other tasks assigned. I have changed the holiday start and end to date format not timestamp this makes  sense. But the task needs to be timestamp  because the task might only take 2 hours.  Again thanks for your time...

Comment: The result i am getting emp  1 jon smith epm 2 mark road emp2 mark road epm 2 mark road emp 2 mark road but mark should not be available thanks again

Comment: Hi Will really struggling with this my project is due in at college (first year) onMonday. Do you think it would be better to query the people between the dates then query that against the employeesId list something like where result id not in employee list. Lost and would appreciate some help please if you have time Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have the right tools to test right now but here is what you can try to do:

when using date comparison:

- try to convert/cast to DATE (make sure time is not included) to make sure the result is correct.
- as far as I know when using between the start and end date are also included (maybe in some RDMS feature)

Also for including holiday, what you can do is like this (either):

- first join with holiday table first then with the result join again with the task assigned table.

or

- first join with task assigned table then with the result join again with the holiday table

Sorry for no code included, as I have no time to setup.

Comment: also instead of between you can try use > < checking just to make sure it works.

Comment: I have change the holiday to date format not timestamp the task still needs to be timestamp because the tack might only take 2 hours.

Comment: Hi, I am still figuring out how to use inner join to get the result you wanted, but here is the query for non inner join syntax:

`select * from emp as e
where e.id in 
(select h.emp_id from holiday as h where h.end_date < '2013-08-07' and '2013-08-07' > h.start_date )
and
e.id in
(select t.emp_id from task as t where t.end_date < '2013-08-07 17:00:00' and '2013-08-07 17:00:00' > t.start_date )`

of course change the table name, column name and date string to your value

Comment: Hi, sorry my last answer was without a date range, but you can modify to check it in a date range.

Comment: 1 question though, if you are looking for employees that are finished with task and holiday should not you just check any task and holiday end date that is < than current date? because doing it in a date range means any employer's task/holiday's end date that are still working within the date range specified.

Comment: The problem with that is if employees have future holidays and task already in the database.What I am looking at is select the employees between dates or < > then start  and end date  then query that array against the employees list eg. <code> "SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `empid` NOT IN ($list) </code> this will give me what i am looking for..